# How do I get a html post request to use a specific charset?

Tags: html, post, character-encoding

I am trying to post a form using an encoding that was previously chosen by the recipient.
The problem I am facing is that I can't seem to get the encoding of the swedish characters `åäö` to be translated correctly. Consider the following form:

```
<form accept-charset="ISO-8859-1" action="http://httpbin.org/post" method="post" id="aForm">
    <input type="hidden" name="hej" value="köttfärssås"/>
    <input type="submit"/>
</form>
```

Posting this using Chrome gives me the following result:

```
{
  "args": {}, 
  "data": "", 
  "files": {}, 
  "form": {
    "hej": "k\ufffdttf\ufffdrss\ufffds"
  }, 
  "headers": {
    "Accept": "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8", 
    "Accept-Encoding": "gzip, deflate", 
    "Accept-Language": "sv-SE,sv;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.6,en;q=0.4", 
    "Cache-Control": "max-age=0", 
    "Content-Length": "21", 
    "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded", 
    "Host": "httpbin.org", 
    "Origin": "null", 
    "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/40.0.2214.93 Safari/537.36"
  }, 
  "json": null, 
  "origin": "85.119.130.112", 
  "url": "http://httpbin.org/post"
}
```

Not only are the `åäö` characters jumbled, there are no headers here showing which encoding is being used. What am I missing here?

I have also tried using `<meta charset="ISO-8859-1">` and `<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=ISO-8859-1">`, but with no success.

So, how do I force the form to use the encoding of my choice?